# How to eager load the nested relationship in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

I have three entities **User, Blog and Comments**. I can load the user blog with the below code:

```
$userBlogs = User::with('blogs')->get();
```

But how can I eager load the comments related to each blog?

**User:**

```
public function blogs() {
    return $this->hasMany(Blog::class);
}
```

**Blog:**

```
public function comments() {
  return $this->hasMany(Comments::class);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
$userBlogs = User::with('blogs.comments')->get();
```

or you can

```
$userBlogs  = User::with(['blogs' => function ($query) {
    $query->with('comments');
}]
```